# custom exception class, using a base class, with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, exception, concatenation, stdstring, const-char

So I'm setting up custom exception classes for a program I am writing. I'm creating a catch-all base class, that I will use primarily as a generic exception. This base class will be inherited by several other custom exceptions. Here is the base class and one of the additional exception classes, there will be 10+ child classes that inherit from the parent class.

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

class AgentException : public std::exception
{

protected:
  char *msg;

public:
  AgentException() : msg("AgentException"){};
  AgentException(char *m) : msg(m){};
  AgentException(char *m, std::string d)
  {

    strcat(m, d.c_str()); //aware this fails. its a segmentation fault
  };
  ~AgentException() = default;

  const char *what() const throw()
  {

    return (const char *)msg;
  }
};

class ConnectionFailed : public AgentException
{

private:
  std::string eType = "ConnectionFailed";

public:
  ConnectionFailed() : AgentException("ConnectionFailed"){};
  ConnectionFailed(std::string d) : AgentException("ConnectionFailed: ", d){};
  ~ConnectionFailed() = default;
};
```

I'm aware with the above code that what() will not currently return anything as the member variable is not being assigned. I left that out, because I'm getting a segmentation fault from the strcat() call.

I've created multiple constructors for the parent class, as there will be times that I want the default value, a single value, or even two arguments passed. In the case of the child class, it will always be passing at least the class ID to the parent, where in some cases I may need to pass a string variable along with the class id. The string variable, std::string, is a must. Those were the directives I was given to use.

Originally I set up all message variables as *std::string* within the classes, but I ultimately ran into a problem related to the *what()* function. I couldn't figure out how to convert the *std::string* to return as a *const char**. After doing some research, I found out that it was a bad idea to utilize strings within an exception class, as what's going to catch any exceptions that may occur within

So I converted everything back to *const char**, but now I can't seem to get a return from *what()*. The problems all stem from my inability to figure out the concatenation of the different types.

I can get something working passably with this change to the AgentException class.

```
protected:
  char msg[100];

public:
  // AgentException() : msg("AgentException"){};
  // AgentException(char *m) : msg(m){};
  AgentException(const char *m, std::string d)
  {

    strcpy(msg, m);
    strcat(msg, d.c_str());
    
  };
```

I can make this change work overall, but it doesn't feel like it's the correct way of doing this. Could someone provide me some insight into the changes they would make to this setup?

I'm currently testing by throwing either the AgentException or ConnectionFailed exception and catching with the Base AgentException. I've been rotating to see if there are any different reactions.

```
try
  {
    throw ConnectionFailed("test");
  }
  catch (const AgentException &e)
  {

    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    std::cout << "_________________" << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: `AgentException(char *m, std::string d)` does not initialize the member returned from `what` resulting in undefined behaviour in the first alternative. Furthermore are you coding pre C++11 code? Otherwise the signature of `what` should be `const char* what() const noexcept;` and you could add `override` to have the compiler check that the signature matches the one in the base class.

Comment: @fabian I pointed out in the first section of code that it's currently throwing an exception.  I didn't assign it to the member, because the strcat doesn't work. I can make it work by making changes in the second section of the code.

Comment: Are you catching the exceptions by value by any chance? Is there a reason you aren't deriving from `std::runtime_error` and letting it deal with storing the `what` message?

Comment: @AlanBirtles So I've updated my post to show you the section of code I'm using to test the exceptions. in regard to not deriving from std::runtime_error, I don't have an answer. I'll read up on that some more. Does it manage multiple arguments with the what message?

Comment: it returns from `what` whatever you pass it in the constructor, you'd still need to concatenate strings to build that message but you can just do that with `std::string`

Comment: `strcat(m, d.c_str())` assumes that `m` is already pointing at an array with sufficient unused space to append the contents of `d.c_str()`. In your first version, you do nothing to ensure that assumption holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Silvio mentioned in another comment, you can't use `strcat` if the buffer can't contain the resulting string.  In this case, you also have the problem that you're passing a `const char *` to `strcat` which is a no no (literal strings are const).

I suggest that you change your `msg` variable to a `std::string`.  It will then be able to grow to accommodate the concatenated message, and manage the memory for you.

```
class AgentException : public std::exception
{

protected:
  std::string msg;

public:
  AgentException() : msg("AgentException") {};
  AgentException(const char *m) : msg(m){};
  AgentException(const char *m, const std::string& d)
  {
      msg = m + d;
  };
  ~AgentException() = default;

  const char *what() const throw()
  {
      return msg.c_str();
  }
};

class ConnectionFailed : public AgentException
{
public:
  ConnectionFailed() : AgentException("ConnectionFailed"){};
  ConnectionFailed(const std::string& d) : AgentException("ConnectionFailed: ", d){};
  ~ConnectionFailed() = default;
};
```

Comment: I was under the impression that using std::string as part of the member variables in exceptions was a bad practice, as there was no way to catch errors.

Comment: I wouldn't use std::string for an "out of memory" exception because the string needs to allocate.  But there's no way to do what you need without allocating, and allocating in an exception on it's own isn't necessarily a problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)

> `char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );`
>
> ...
>
> The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character.

So if you call this constructor with a `char*` that's exactly big enough to store the *original* string, and then you try to append more onto it, you get undefined behavior. Don't call `strcat` on buffers where you don't know the size. Your second solution, where you pre-allocate 100 characters (assuming that's enough for your use-case) and then use *that* buffer is correct. A fully general solution would call `strlen` twice and allocate a buffer exactly big enough to fit the two strings, but that may be out-of-scope if this is just a simple example.